Pterodactyl i18 browser lanuage detector error
I get this kind of error and i don't know how to fix it!
ERROR in ./node_modules/i18next-browser-languagedetector/dist/esm/i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector.js 134:58
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (134:58)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|         search
|       } = window.location;
>       if (!window.location.search && window.location.hash?.indexOf('?') > -1) {
|         search = window.location.hash.substring(window.location.hash.indexOf('?'));
|       }
 @ ./resources/scripts/i18n.ts 5:0-64 11:67-83
 @ ./resources/scripts/index.tsx
 @ multi react-hot-loader/patch ./resources/scripts/index.tsx
error Command failed with exit code 2.

I tried other loaders such as babel and more, none worked. But i thought it would!
